# Clear an Rx.Observable bufferCount with an event driven Timeout?

Tags: javascript, timeout, buffer, rxjs, observable

I'm using [rxjs 5.0](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-bufferCount):

How can I set a timeout, on this buffer.  So that it will clear the bufferCount (11) when no keyup events happen for 5 seconds?

```
var keys = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'keyup');
var buffered = keys.bufferCount(11,1);
buffered.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append a [`timeoutWith`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-timeoutWith), which could return a *fresh* `buffered` after a certain timeout (5seconds in your case).

```js
const keys$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, "keyup")
  .map(ev => ev.keyCode|| ev.which); // this is just to have a readable output here in the SO-console
  
const buffered$ = keys$
  .bufferCount(3,1)  // replaced your 11 with 3 for easy demonstration
  .timeoutWith(2000, Rx.Observable.defer(() => { // replaced 5 with 2 seconds (easier to test here)
     console.log("New Buffer!");
     return buffered$;
  }));

buffered$.subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

---

**As an improvement**, this could be even enhanced to only start the stream on the *first* stroke, otherwise we would have a constant timeout running (not critical, but could still be prevented).

```js
const keys$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, "keyup")
  .map(ev => ev.keyCode|| ev.which); // this is just to have a readable output here in the SO-console

const buffered$ = keys$
  .take(1)
  .switchMap(firstKey => {
    console.log("New Buffer!");
    return keys$
     .startWith(firstKey)
     .bufferCount(3,1)  // replaced your 11 with 3 for easy demonstration
     .timeoutWith(2000, Rx.Observable.defer(() => buffered$)); // replaced 5 with 2 seconds (easier to test here)
  });

buffered$.subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have another (and probably easier to understand) solution using `window` and `switchMap()`:

```
var keys = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document.getElementById('myinput'), 'keyup')
  .map(event => event.keyCode)
  .share();

var buffered = keys
  .window(keys.debounceTime(5000))
  .switchMap(observable => observable.bufferCount(5, 1))
  .filter(buffer => buffer.length === 5);

buffered.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

See demo: https://jsbin.com/cakoru/17/edit?js,console,output

When you don't type for at least 5s the `window()` operator creates a new Observable that is subscribed internally in `switchMap()` and chained with a new `.bufferCount()` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
const keys$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'keyup').map(ev => ev.keyCode|| ev.which);

keys$
  .debounceTime(5000)
  .startWith({})
  .switchMap(x => keys$.bufferCount(11, 1))
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Here we've got a stream that yields a value each time typing stops for five seconds (kicked off with a dummy value) that switchMaps into a bufferCount.